# Open Outlook with attachment in silverlight without Out of Browser

Tags: outlook, silverlight-5.0

I want to open outlook and attach one file with this mail using silverlight.

My silverlight application is not running in OOB(Out of Browser) mode.

How can i open outlook with attachment using silverlight and without OOB mode?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. Remember that Silverlight is a plugin that runs on client machines, so you have limited access to the local machine (client).

In the other hand, you can run executables (outlook.exe) if the user have the software (MS Outlook) if you full trust your app and modify some registry values in client machine.

Hope it helps.